# updating classes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am looking for a solution to my problem. I have a class that creates a UIButton for me:

```
class MenuButton: UIButton {

    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat

    required init(parent: UIView = UIView(), x: CGFloat = 0, y: CGFloat = 0, width: CGFloat = 40, height: CGFloat = 40) {

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        backgroundColor = global.labelColor
        setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2

        if x < 0 {
            frame = CGRect(x: superview?.frame.width ?? 0 - abs(x) - frame.width, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        }

        if y < 0 {
            frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: superview?.frame.height ?? 0 - abs(y) - frame.height, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then I add a constant that is assigned to this class:

```
let pauseButton = MenuButton()
```

This works fine and the button is shown on the scene with everything to default. Now I want to add those things in the viewDidLoad() (I added the subview to acces it in the class):

```
view.addSubview(pauseButton)
pauseButton.x = -20
pauseButton.y = 20
pauseButton.width = 40
pauseButton.height = 40
```

This does not update the stuff I specified in the init(). How do I call the init again (without doing pauseButton = MenuButton() again) or is there like an update() I can use?

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: try to move view.addsubview to the bottom

Comment: @Tobi This does not work. I need to know the superview in the class, so it needs to be set before the other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually pass those values in the initializer as below,

```
let pauseButton = MenuButton(parent: view, x: -20, y: 20, width: 40, height: 40)
```

If you want to make your button update immediately as you change any of these properties then you can use `didSet` callback to set the `frame` as below,

```
class MenuButton: UIButton {

    var x: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            self.updateFrame()
        }
    }

    var y: CGFloat  {
        didSet {
            self.updateFrame()
        }
    }

    var width: CGFloat  {
        didSet {
            self.updateFrame()
        }
    }

    var height: CGFloat  {
        didSet {
            self.updateFrame()
        }
    }

    private func updateFrame() {
        frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }

    required init(parent: UIView = UIView(), x: CGFloat = 0, y: CGFloat = 0, width: CGFloat = 40, height: CGFloat = 40) {

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        backgroundColor = .green
        setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2

        if x < 0 {
            frame = CGRect(x: superview?.frame.width ?? 0 - abs(x) - frame.width, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        }

        if y < 0 {
            frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: superview?.frame.height ?? 0 - abs(y) - frame.height, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each `UIViewController` have `UIView` accessed inside of it as `view`
you are adding the subview already here.

```
view.addSubview(pauseButton)
```

so just pass it into the `init()` you have and add it there.

your code could be something like this.

```
class MenuButton: UIButton {


var x: CGFloat
var y: CGFloat
var width: CGFloat
var height: CGFloat

required init(parent: UIView = UIView(), x: CGFloat = 0, y: CGFloat = 0, width: CGFloat = 40, height: CGFloat = 40) {

    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height

    super.init(frame: .zero)

    frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    backgroundColor = global.labelColor
    setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2

    if x < 0 {
        frame = CGRect(x: superview?.frame.width ?? 0 - abs(x) - frame.width, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    }

    if y < 0 {
        frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: superview?.frame.height ?? 0 - abs(y) - frame.height, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    }
    parent.addSubview(self)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")


   }
}
```

And use it in `ViewDidLoad` like this.

```
let _ = MenuButton(parent: view, x: -20, y: 20, width: 40, height: 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

init() method is called only once when you instantiating your button. You should try to instantiate the button with the desired properties. Try something like this:

```
let pauseButton = MenuButton(parent: UIView(), x: -20, y: 20, width: 40, height:40)
```

Then in your viewDidLoad() method you can have just this line:

```
view.addSubview(pauseButton)
```

Another problem that I noticed is that you are referencing to the superview in your init() method, but superview is always nil in that case, since your button is not yet added as a subview.

Comment: You should also replace superview from your init() method with parent parameter.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ?

```
 button.frame = CGRect(x:xPostion, y:yPostion, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)
```

or u can declare a funtion called updateFrame in ur Menu button class and pass new position as argument , like this :

```
func updateFrame(x:CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
self.frame = CGRect(x:xPostion, y:yPostion, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)
}
```

and in your VideDidLoad :

```
button.updateFrame(x:xPostion, y:yPostion, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)
```

what you are doing at the moment is just assigning some values to your Button's properties, how should your button knows to use them to reset its frame ??